# is NSAppTransportSecurity same as App Transport Security in Info.plist? xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode7.3, app-transport-security

I need to allow access to few http domains but my Info.plist does not have the setting 'NS App Transport Security', which all other questions on this state I need. I have found the key for 'App Transport Security Settings', added 'Exception Domains', and added the domains under that. (There are no subkeys to add under teh domains). I presume it is the same as 'NS' App Transport Security? [image]But it is not working.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.  Xcode just does some translations of some of the Info.plist values to make them more readable.  You can right click on the Info.plist file and select the "Show Raw Keys / Values" menu item to seethe actual values if you want to see the NSAppTransportSecurity valyes:

[image]